# What does the language {a, b, c}* exactly mean? How will the automaton for this look like?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars

What does the language {a, b, c}* exactly mean?

Comment: What have you tried?  We expect you to make a significant effort to try to solve your own problem before asking here, including studying standard references.  The meaning of this notation is explained in standard textbooks -- did you read them?  If you didn't read them, then your question is inappropriate here (there is little value in us repeating standard material).  If you did read them, what specifically were you confused about?  What are your thoughts?  A one-sentence question is rarely a good fit for this site.  Also, only one question per question, please.  See the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finite words composed of the characters $a,b$ & $c$ and the empty word are part of the language $\{a,b,c\}^*$. The automaton has one state which is the starting and ending state. That state has 3 recursive edges which are reading $a$,$b$ and $c$.

Comment: Including the empty word...

Answer (score 0):

It means this Language can 'generate' any string using the alphabets $a, b, c$, including the empty string $\epsilon$

There is no bound on the length of the string generated.

Here's a NFA that accepts such a language:

[image]

Comment: Oops, I guess the answer was already there.

Comment: You wrote "NFA", but I think it's a DFA?